# How to ssh into windows 10 virtual box guest os from linux host

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ssh, virtualbox

I have a work PC which runs Manjaro as the host OS but we have windows 10 running in virtual box as a guest OS. For security reasons's IT only allows us to connect to the vpn within the VM.

Is there a way to ssh via a bridged network to an ssh server running on the VM such that I can forward these requests to servers running on my works network ?

I had tried setting up a server in wsl but it doesn't seem accessible to the host os.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:
I am trying to connect my host os (manjaro) to the network made accessible via vpn on the guest os (windows 10). Specifically I wish to do so so that I can ssh from the host os to machines on the vpn.

Comment: @ReginaldMarr - Your one question in that case, depends on an answer to a single question, are you able to connect Manjaro to the VPN.  If you cannot then the machine, connected to the VPN, will be inaccessible to Manjaro.  You can [edit] your question so it includes this vital information required to answer your question.

Comment: @ReginaldMarr - Please [edit] your question before submitting any additional information as a comment.

Comment: ok so you have a running ssh server, but may still be having basic network or firewall issues. is the IP address for the guest a valid one, on the same LAN as the host? also, it is possible that the VPN itself is the issue. with the VPN disabled, are you able to connect to SSH?

Comment: yeah it is but when I try to ping it I get 100% packet loss
edit:
vpn doesn't affect this

Comment: can the guest ping out to known good IPs on the LAN? if so your issue is likely firewall.

Comment: Yes from the host I can ssh into machines as well as ping them. I'm sorry I'm not super familiar with windows firewalls. Could you point me in the direction of how to properly configure it ?

Comment: I mean from the **guest**, can you connect to other systems on your LAN?